# Selecting value where name like value and name like other value in many to one temp table query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to build a new search parameter for an asset tracking tool and am using two temp tables joind and queried against since assets may have more than one software I need a and conditional that will find only ones that have the ...value in them attached to any name, but filter out the ones potential matches that don't match any longer: in this case software.I know i have to be doing something wrong, but I just cant see it... Below is the code used to generate the temp tables used later in the search...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lookup_tbl_2 SELECT am_software.id,
            am_software.asset_name,
            am_software.sw_name,
            am_software.sw_key,
            am_software.sw_osver
        FROM am_software
        UNION ALL
        SELECT am_software_archive.id,
            am_software_archive.asset_name,
            am_software_archive.sw_name,
            am_software_archive.sw_key,
            am_software_archive.sw_osver
        FROM am_software_archive;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lookup_tbl_1 SELECT am_assets.id,
            am_assets.asset_name,
            am_assets.asset_family,
            am_assets.asset_type,
            am_assets.asset_location,
            am_assets.asset_manufacturer,
            am_assets.asset_model,
            am_assets.asset_serial,
            am_assets.asset_status,
            am_assets.asset_retired_on,
            am_networks.connection_type,
            CASE WHEN am_networks.ipa_pointer = 1 THEN 'Dynamic' ELSE CONCAT_WS('.', am_ip_addresses.ip_address, am_networks.ip_address) END AS 'display_address'
        FROM am_assets
        JOIN am_networks ON am_assets.asset_name = am_networks.asset_name
        JOIN am_locations ON am_assets.asset_location = am_locations.id
        JOIN am_asset_family ON am_assets.asset_family = am_asset_family.id
        JOIN am_asset_type ON am_assets.asset_type = am_asset_type.id
        JOIN am_ip_addresses ON am_networks.ipa_pointer = am_ip_addresses.id
        JOIN am_connection_types ON am_networks.connection_type = am_connection_types.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT am_asset_archive.id,
            am_asset_archive.asset_name,
            am_asset_archive.asset_family,
            am_asset_archive.asset_type,
            am_asset_archive.asset_location,
            am_asset_archive.asset_manufacturer,
            am_asset_archive.asset_model,
            am_asset_archive.asset_serial,
            am_asset_archive.asset_status,
            am_asset_archive.asset_retired_on,
            am_network_archive.connection_type,
            CASE WHEN am_network_archive.ipa_pointer = 1 THEN 'Dynamic' ELSE CONCAT_WS('.', am_ip_addresses.ip_address, am_network_archive.ip_address) END AS 'display_address'
        FROM am_asset_archive
        JOIN am_network_archive ON am_asset_archive.asset_name = am_network_archive.asset_name
        JOIN am_locations ON am_asset_archive.asset_location = am_locations.id
        JOIN am_asset_family ON am_asset_archive.asset_family = am_asset_family.id
        JOIN am_asset_type ON am_asset_archive.asset_type = am_asset_type.id
        JOIN am_ip_addresses ON am_network_archive.ipa_pointer = am_ip_addresses.id
        JOIN am_connection_types ON am_network_archive.connection_type = am_connection_types.id;
```

Again the goal is to search through the temp tables and return values to the ui; so this is where I am running into trouble:

```sql
    SELECT lookup_tbl_1.asset_name as 'asset_name' 
    FROM lookup_tbl_1 
    JOIN lookup_tbl_2 
    ON lookup_tbl_1.asset_name = lookup_tbl_2.asset_name 
    WHERE lookup_tbl_2.sw_name LIKE 'Office 2010' AND lookup_tbl_2.sw_name LIKE 'Atom'
    AND lookup_tbl_1.asset_location = 5;
```

The software names are text and won't have to have the like but even when I use:

```sql
    SELECT lookup_tbl_1.asset_name as 'asset_name' 
    FROM lookup_tbl_1 
    JOIN lookup_tbl_2 
    ON lookup_tbl_1.asset_name = lookup_tbl_2.asset_name 
    WHERE lookup_tbl_2.sw_name = 'Office 2010' 
    AND lookup_tbl_2.sw_name = 'Atom'
    AND lookup_tbl_1.asset_location = 5;
```

The values are known to be tied to a specific asset I am trying to get to display the assets name, It works if i drop one of the software name conditions (sw_name) but not when there are more than one...

I have been searching for a working solution, and have tried thing like:

```sql
WHERE lookup_tbl_2.sw_name LIKE 'Office 2010' AND 'Atom'
```

```sql
WHERE lookup_tbl_2.sw_name LIKE 'Office 2010' 'Atom'
```

```sql
WHERE lookup_tbl_2.sw_name = 'Office 2010' AND 'Atom'
```

```sql
WHERE (find_in_set('Office 2010', lookup_tbl_2.sw_name)>0 AND find_in_set('Atom', lookup_tbl_2.sw_name)>0)
```

all return the same empty result, but removing the second sw_name conditional works fine...

Expected: Should return a list of asset names such as 'JWW90120' (actual asset name value that should be included in the expected list as it matches all the conditionals).

Actual: empty results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help form a colleague who helped me work though it after troubleshooting a few error s we finally got it to work...

the working code:

```sql
    SELECT lookup_tbl_1.asset_name FROM lookup_tbl_1 WHERE lookup_tbl_1.asset_location = 5 
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT lookup_tbl_2.asset_name FROM lookup_tbl_2 WHERE
                lookup_tbl_1.asset_name = lookup_tbl_2.asset_name AND
                lookup_tbl_2.sw_name in ('Office 2010', 'Atom')
            );
```

This issue has been resolved... Hope it may help some one else that may find themselves in this situation in the future.

Comment: For `AND` operation found that using `GROUP BY table_name.primary_key HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table_name.column_searched) = num_vals_in_IN` worked to exclude where values didn't all exist in the asset by name.
*edited for structure.